# BackBone and sessionsStorage

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using Backbone and JQuery to create an input form in a MVC3-project. I use Backbone to create inputsboxes, and I am using sessionStorage function in Jquery to fold and unfold items within a menu..

If I try to use the window.sessionStorage.key(i), the html created by Backbone disapper, but only in IE:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= window.sessionStorage.length; i++) {
      key = window.sessionStorage.key(i);
         if (key != null) {
              //Unfold menu item  on key;
            }
        }
```

I can make this work in Chrome..

The update-function for menu items works in IE...

```
function updateSession(element) {
                if (window.sessionStorage[element.id] == element.id) {
                    alert("Just delete the item");
                    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(element.id); 
                }
                else {
                    window.sessionStorage.setItem(element.id, element.id); 
                    alert("Just set the item");
                }
            }
```

Why is this happening? I tried the Jquery.noConflict..

Comment: Lasse, have you already found an answer? If yes, please post it..

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://caniuse.com/#namevalue-storage

Comment: In this case, check that you have the right values in key = window.sessionStorage.key(i). If that works, the mystery lies in the part that you did not include ( //Unfold menu item  on key; )

Comment: I just store a string - the name of the items.. That should be supported. I can also unfold a menu item, if I give the function a specific string as Item7